# I am having trouble determining whether two c# strings are sorted

Tags: c#, string, unit-testing, sorting

I have created a method of determining whether two strings are sorted.  All of my test cases work except for one.  The code is below.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool test1 = isSorted("test1", "test2");
        bool test2 = isSorted("4576", "4567");
        bool test3 = isSorted("test10", "test11");
        bool test4 = isSorted("abdc", "abcd");
    }

    public static bool isSorted(string MyFirstString, string MySecondString)
    {
        string MyFirstCutString = MyFirstString.ToLower();
        string MySecondCutString = MySecondString.ToLower();

        if (MyFirstString.Length > MySecondString.Length)
            MyFirstCutString = MyFirstCutString.Substring(0, MySecondString.Length);
        else if (MySecondString.Length > MyFirstString.Length)
            MySecondCutString = MySecondCutString.Substring(0, MyFirstCutString.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < MyFirstCutString.Length; i++)
        {
            if (getNumberic(MyFirstCutString[i]) > getNumberic(MySecondCutString[i]))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static int getNumberic(char myLetter)
    {
        switch (myLetter)
        {
            case 'a':
                return 1;
            case 'b':
                return 2;
            case 'c':
                return 3;
            case 'd':
                return 4;
            case 'e':
                return 5;
            case 'f':
                return 6;
            case 'g':
                return 7;
            case 'h':
                return 8;
            case 'i':
                return 9;
            case 'j':
                return 10;
            case 'k':
                return 11;
            case 'l':
                return 12;
            case 'm':
                return 13;
            case 'n':
                return 14;
            case 'o':
                return 15;
            case 'p':
                return 16;
            case 'q':
                return 17;
            case 'r':
                return 18;
            case 's':
                return 19;
            case 't':
                return 20;
            case 'u':
                return 21;
            case 'v':
                return 22;
            case 'w':
                return 23;
            case 'x':
                return 24;
            case 'y':
                return 25;
            case 'z':
                return 26;
            case 'O':
                return 27;
            case '1':
                return 28;
            case '2':
                return 29;
            case '3':
                return 30;
            case '4':
                return 31;
            case '5':
                return 32;
            case '6':
                return 33;
            case '7':
                return 34;
            case '8':
                return 35;
            case '9':
                return 36;
            default:
                return 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

The results of the tests are as follows:

```
test1 result is true
test2 result is false
test3 result is false (NOT GOOD!)
test4 result is true
```

I do not see any flaws in my logic.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, why aren't you using `string.Compare`?

Comment: A few more test cases, for which I'm not sure if they behave as you like: Both `"A","B"` and `"B","A"` are considered sorted. And both `"ab","a"` and `"a","ab"` are considered sorted.

Comment: Using your code test4 result is `false`, not true as you write... Is this what you need?

Comment: @Marco - you are correct sir, I made a mistake when I was retyping the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mixed up `O` and `0` in the switch. This means `0` gets the numeric value `1000`, and sorts behind `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `0` you have `O` in the getNumberic method.

By the way, I would rewrite it at least like this:

```
    public static int getNumberic( char c )
    {
        if( c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' )
        {
            return c - 'a';
        }
        else if( c >= '0' && c <= '9' )
        {
            return 'z' + c - '0';
        }
        else
        {
            return 1000;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know. But doesn't matter for sorting purposes.

Comment: certainly it does. `isSorted("zb", "0a")`

Comment: Ok, I indeed have a "bug", but not the one you think I have. The one you're keeping in mind would be there if I had `'z' - 'a' + c - '0'`. But my code actually works fine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you search, but what do you think about this?

```
public bool isSorted(string s1, string s2)
{
    return s1.ToLower().CompareTo(s2.ToLower()) < 0;
}
```

or

```
public bool isSorted(string s1, string s2)
{
    return String.Compare(s1, s2, true) < 0;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx says to avoid `string.CompareTo`, but to use `string.Compare` instead.

Comment: @MrLister: thanks, you're right. I've just updated my answer. I don't understand why OP needs those long self-written functions... What do you think?

Comment: @Marco He probably wants a custom sort order. In particular ASCII digits after lowercase ASCII letters, and all other characters after that.

Comment: @Marco I think if the OP is learning about sorting methods, writing compare functions yourself is a good method of getting to understand these things. The OP's example would need 127 cases in the switch for ASCII though, and over a million cases for Unicode.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: don't know. I've already upvoted your answer because is the correct one, but I think to leave my answer as I think it's not wrong :)